# Footer Extra Space in SSRS Matrix Report

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

After several hours and scrolling through hundreds of pages, I was not able to find a solution for this. So here goes my question

I have created a matrix report on SSRS with several groups.The report works fine but the group footers leave a large amount of space (empty) when collapsed. Let me explain it with the help of some screenshots

[image: When Report is collapsed the extra space is displayed]

I am looking for a solution to remove this space in the collapsed report (above screenshot). I tried parsing the report column as HTML and deploying it to the report server but could not even come closer. 
Here is the same report when the groups are expanded.

[image: Groups Expanded]

**Update:**

Here is a screenshot of the report design

[image: Report Design]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The space is there for you hidden data.

How about hiding the columns as well? Just use the same textbox for the control.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. But I tried that and getting the following error - The tablix "Tablix1" has 'GroupHeader1' as a toggle item. Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item, and cannot be contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope has a parent. 
Please Help!

Comment: the column visibility is grayed out. Maybe because it's a group

Comment: What cell are you using for your toggle? I think **Revenue** should work

Comment: The columns separated by color are the different row groups.I updated the question with the design screenshot.

Comment: Are you able to toggle it with Header1 (Revenue) or is it considered inside the scope? If it doesn;t work, try using a text box outside the table.

Comment: I am able to toggle but the column visibility is not available as it is a row group and not a column group in matrix report.